# Debian or Fedora/CentOS.. which would be better suited for hardware programmer's needs

Tags: debian, centos, fedora

Since I'm stuck in a "can't decide on which path to choose" loop concerning choosing a proper Linux distro for a workstation, I need a little help in term's of typical hardware/software programmer's needs.

My two big favorites are Debian and Fedora/CentOS. I already know both have great community support in terms of development, but I'm looking for that extra spark, a slight edge that would lean me to one of them.

Feedback would be very appreciated.

Comment: Just try them both, my friend. It's not like it'll cost you a fortune. My fav is debian, but then again, that'll only start a distro war. Perhaps you don't have a lot of linux experience? In that case it is best to just dive in with either, and don't procrastinate!

Answer (score 1):

I'm currently working on Debian and just got out of "CentOS period". Don't get me wrong, CentOS is a great system with it's stability, speed and over all feel. What got me thinking was it's orientation focused more on sysadmins, then on developers alike. Thus my question.. Debian seems similar in reliability and, IMHO, has a larger developer community, which is very important to me. Well, after reading Your opinions, the only way is to dive into Debian myself and find out what suits me better..

Answer (score 0):

I agree, try them both.  Have you used VirtualBox or VMWare?  Using these tools you can try both at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

And what about Gentoo? Did a little research on the web, and several sources recommend it because of "compilers on sight" must be. Even though it's much tougher to establish and maintain, maybe the fun (by "fun" I mean knowledge development) after is worth digging?